# how to set Datatable as datasource in ReportViewer

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, reportviewer, localreport

I was searching in the last question about `Datatable` as `datasource` in `ReportViewer` and i found this as solution

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("value", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("price", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("quantity", typeof(string));

table.Rows.Add("test1","10","20");
table.Rows.Add("test2", "10", "20");

reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

ReportDataSource rprtDTSource = new ReportDataSource("TITLE",table);

reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rprtDTSource);
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

but i get this image as result

[image]

what is the problem ??

Comment: Where do you set the report for your report viewer? I suppose you have a report as embedded resource and then you can set the report source something like this: `this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Namespace.ReportName.rdlc";`

Comment: i just have and data table and report viewer, how i can display the data inside the report viewer @RezaAghaei

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you have forgotten to set the report source for your report viewer control. You can set the report source using either of this options:

- [`LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport.reportembeddedresource.aspx) : The name of the report-embedded resource.
- [`LocalReport.ReportPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport.reportpath.aspx) : The file system path of the local report.
- [`LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(Stream)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252134.aspx): Loads a report definition for processing using a Stream.
- [`LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(TextReader)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252177.aspx) Loads a report definition from the local file system using a TextReader.

For example, I suppose you have added a report to your project, so you can show it in the report viewer this way:

```
var reportDataSource1 = new ReportDataSource("NameOfReportDataSet", YourDataTable);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Namespace.ReportName.rdlc";
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Also you can simply set the report of the report viewer using designer. Put a report viewer on your form and click on top-right arrow to open the smart tag window of report viewer, then choose a report from combo box.

[image]

Comment: i just have and data table and report viewer, how i can display the data inside the report viewer, can you give me an example?? please !

Comment: yes, i did this action add a new empty report to project and choose it as resource for report viewer

Comment: but how i can pass the datatable items to report ??

Comment: Creating an empty report is useless. You should add a data source to your report and design the report. Then pass your data to report. You can use the report wizard.

Comment: OK,  i have create new report from database (table) the report display the data no problem, but how i can pass "DataTable table " items to report  ??

Comment: Good job, how did you show data of database in your report.  You can show data of a custom data table the same way. Also you should pay attention, your custom data table schema should be like the table you used for creating report.

Comment: Also you should know if you have for example `ProductDataTable` you don't need to create a custom table and pass it to your report, you can use that table. Specially if you have created a data set that contains the data table and you are using a binding source as data source of report, so you can simply add some row to the the instance of `yourSataSet.YourTable.Rows` and then `RefreshReport`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98977/discussion-between-a-sawadeh-and-reza-aghaei).

Comment: By the way, just to mention if you don't know, When you [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308647), you can also vote for it. It's not compulsory at all but its reasonable and recommended. If you know or if you voted, just ignore the comment :)

Comment: @RodrigoRodriguez You're welcome, happy to hear it was helpful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add source like below

```
LocalReport report = new LocalReport();

string startupPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
report.ReportPath = startupPath + @"\RDCLTemplate.rdlc";
report.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong, ReportDataSource ctor you are using needs data source in first parameter i.e. a named data source. You're not supplying this, you need the DataTable name.

Update your code to this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.TableName = "myDataTable";
//Fill Datatable
ReportDataSource source = new ReportDataSource("myDataTable", dt);
```