# Pass DataTable to ReportViewer

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datatable, reportviewer

I am trying to pass a datatable to a reportviewer which I fill by code, is there a way to do that? I tried this but nothing happened:

```
Dim bs As BindingSource
        bs = New BindingSource()
        bs.DataSource = DataTablefillbycode
        Dim rs As ReportDataSource
        rs = New ReportDataSource()
        rs.Name = "Tabletest"
        rs.Value = bs
        form2.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
        form2.ReportViewer1.Reset()
        form2.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Test.Report1.rdlc"
        form2.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
        form2.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rs)

        form2.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
      
        form2.ShowDialog()
```

PS : The GridView works fine with the table "Tablefillbycode"

[image: The ReportViewer]

Comment: I think BindingSource is going to return a DataView object, not DataTable, which the Viewer needs (correct me if I'm wrong here).  Try "Dim oDt as DataTable = DirectCast(bs.DataSource,DataView).ToTable()" And then "rs.Value = oDt" and let me know if it works.

Comment: What's the name of `DataSet` in your report?

Comment: @Aaron thanks i will try it now

Comment: @RezaAghaei DataSet1

Comment: @Aaron : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'System.Data.DataView'.

Comment: My apologies.  I was almost positive the bindingsource would return a view.

Comment: @Aaron Its fine thanks anw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps to be able to pass data table to your report:

1. I suppose you created a `Report1.rdlc` in root of your project `Test`, so the name of its embedded resource would be `Test.Report1.rdlc`. Also I suppose the name of `DataSet` in your `Report1` is `DataSet1`.
2. Put a report viewer on your `Form2` and set its `Dock` property to `Fill` and set its `Modifier` property to `Public`.
3. In `Form1` I suppose you have a `DataGridView1` that you want to fill it in the `Form_Load` and you will use the same query that you used for creating report.
4. In `Form1` I suppose you have a `Button1` that you want to show `Form2` when you click on `Button1` and you want pass the data of `DataGridView1` to it.

Don't forget to `Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms` in `Form1`

**Code:**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim cn = "data source=(localdb)\v11.0;initial catalog=TestDB;integrated security=True;"
    Dim cmd = "SELECT Id,Name FROM Category"
    Dim adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd, cn)
    Dim table = New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(table)
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = table
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim form2 = New Form2()
    Dim rds= New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", Me.DataGridView1.DataSource)
    form2.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    form2.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
    form2.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Test.Report1.rdlc"
    form2.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Any idea for creating RDLC report at run-time from a DataGridView?**

You might be interested to the following post which explains how you can dynamically convert any DataGridView to an RDLC report at run-time for printing purpose, etc. The post comes withe the full code in a GitHub repo and a download link:

- [Create RDLC report dynamically at run-time from a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40367119/3110834)

Comment: Probably you set the `ReportPath` in `LocalReport` property of `ReportViewer1` in designer. Just drop a `ReportViewer` on `Form2` and use it without any extra settings.

Comment: You can set the report source also using the designer, but then the way you can pass the table to your report is somehow different. Let me know if you tried it using a 1ReportViewer1` without extra settings or if you have any setting on it.

Comment: Test.Report1.rdls should be .rdlc its a silly fault .. anw now i try what u told me to do the ReportViewer is not like the picture in the question (Disabled ) .. but its an empty Reportviewer!

Comment: Just an information i know its late the DataTablefillbycode is a data table witch i create it from a database in my sql management studio, so it dasnot make sense if you told the ReportDataSource to takes source from the DataSet1 because the DataTablefillbycode is created by code and its not showing in the DataSet1 Diagrame

Comment: As I told, I supposed it is an instance of a table (which is filled with data)

Comment: oh yeah thanks ,but how i can fix the problem any idea?

Comment: Let me know what's the problem now and also share the code of creating and filling datatable.

Comment: Can i just do that ?
DataSet1.Tables.Add(DataTablefillbycode )
And then use ur way?

Comment: Is the table that you create report for, is a member of your `DataSet1`?

Comment: No , is there way to add it to be a member ?

Comment: You don't need to do that. Just fill a data table using the query that you created your report and then set the table as I did above.

Comment: Look Do you have an email or something i try to find the answer on google but nothing is clear ! I Try what u tell me to do but the reportviewer still blank,
my datatable is not in dataset because its formed on vb and he takes multiples informations form differents tables in the dataset

Comment: I Read it and i do the same as u asking me to do the difference between your code and mine :
1-  You fill exactly your table from sql to vb, mine is mixed i make a query in tableadabptar and it join more than table 
2- the columns names are not the same in sql and in the vb datatable  because i change it manualy and i put a data in the rows from the mixed table that i make it from the query

Comment: **1-** Having a complex mixed query is not a problem. **2-** you should use the same column names in your query result that you used in your report. In fact the schema of the query that you used for report and the data table you want to pass to the report should be same. **3-** You can simply use the same query that you create in your VB application for your report.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I will try to add the datatable witch i create to database then fill it again

Comment: You can also set the report source using designer. You may find this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34458615/3110834) helpful.