# How to print DataGridView data?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, printing, datagridview

[image: Screenshot of the Window]

Here is my code to Print:

```
Private Sub btnPrint_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
    PrintInvoiceDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
    PrintPreviewDialog.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub PrintInvoiceDoc_PrintPage(sender As System.Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintInvoiceDoc.PrintPage
    Dim CenterAlign As New StringFormat
    CenterAlign.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
    Dim RightAlign As New StringFormat
    CenterAlign.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
    e.Graphics.DrawString("School Name", New Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, New Point(25, 25))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Report", New Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, New Point(1000, 25), RightAlign)
    Dim mRow As Integer = 0
    Dim newpage As Boolean = True
    With DataGridView1
        Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
        fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
        Dim y As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top
        Do While mRow < .RowCount
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)
            Dim x As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
            Dim h As Single = 0
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                Dim rc As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Width, rc.Height)
                If (newpage) Then
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                Else
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Rows(cell.RowIndex).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString(), .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                End If
                x += rc.Width
                h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
            Next
            newpage = False
            y += h
            mRow += 1
            If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
                e.HasMorePages = True
                mRow -= 1
                newpage = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Loop
        mRow = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

So, when hit 'Print' I get the result shown in this image:

[image: Print Screenshot]

Problem #1: I am missing the first row [As you can see]

Problem #2: When the rows are enough that one page is not enough to store all of them, new page is created in infinite loop and same page is repeated so not all data is printed.

Note: I almost don't have any idea about using a `DataGridView` in `PrintDocument`, but any advice/tips are welcome!

Comment: Also please tell me any alternating way to do so... i.e, ReportViewer *Step by step if you could*

Comment: Check out this link.  The original code is for the old `DataGrid` control but later a version for the `DataGridView` was added.  http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?356115-DataGridPrinter-A-class-to-print-data-grid-in-a-nicely-formatted-way

Comment: [Pass DataTable to ReportViewer Vb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511856/pass-datatable-to-reportviewer-vb)

Comment: @jmcilhinney The website appears to be down, can you access to it?

Comment: @Reza Aghaei Ok I'll try that later and inform you...

Comment: I just tested and was able to load that page.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yeah me too able to load now... it's up again... :) Thnx I'll try it...

Comment: @jmcilhinney Hi when I use his code for my project I get the error: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'."

Comment: Hi @Reza Aghaei,



| 

I encountered problem in the following code = `form2.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Test.Report1.rdlc"` 
 

|

Problem: What should I replace with the text "Text"?

Comment: If you add the report at root of your project, the resource name would be `YourProjectName.YourReportName.rdlc`. For example, in my sample since the project name was `Test` and the report name was `Report1`, then the resource name was `Test.Report1.rdlc`

Comment: @Reza Aghaei ,
My project name has space between words... how to write that then?  , i.e, 'My Project Name.vbproj'

Comment: In project properties, look at default namespace.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei Thank You very much! you are awesome .... I want one more help please ..    |     I don't want to show "Id" of the row so is it possible to hide "Id Column"? and is it possible that I can also add the text from textbox1 from Form1 to the reportviewer at the end such that a row at the last of the table of reportviewer?

Comment: With regards to the error message "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'", that suggests that the code assumes that a `DataTable` is bound directly to the grid but you have a `BindingSource`.  You just need to change the code to interrogate the grid to determine the type of its `DataSource` and then treat it accordingly.

Comment: @jmcilhinney How to do that?

Comment: By reading the code, finding where it is assuming that the `DataSource` is a `DataTable` and changing that to check whether it is and, if not, use the `DataSource` of the `BindingSource` instead.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Ok I'll try it later and let you know my result! thank you... :)

Comment: @Reza Aghaei Ok my 1st problem is solved, I am able to hide the id column now successfully just by going to Report.rdlc > then delete the 'Id' Column ...
| Now my 2nd problem still exist that I want add text from the textbox to the last row of the ReportViewer table...

Comment: @Reza Aghaei Hi,
Ok, got the solution for the second problem too! Just used the parameter solution and was successful anyhow thank you for your effort! :)
Solution reference: [Code Project Page](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/607625/passplusvalueplustoplustextboxplusinplusReportView) + [Actual Help from YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yMyHAg60NPA)

Comment: @MohammadZulfikar You'r welcome, Happy to hear you solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

ur first row behind header row... make new rectanglef for ur header row like this....

```
  For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                Dim rc As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
                Dim rc2 As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y - 22, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
                If (newpage) Then
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.LightGray), New RectangleF(x, y - 22, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height))
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc2.Left, rc2.Top, rc2.Width, rc2.Height)
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(dgpembelian.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, cellheaderFont, Brushes.Black, rc2, drawFormat)
                End If
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Width, rc.Height)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(dgpembelian.Rows(cell.RowIndex).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString, .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, drawFormat)
                x += rc.Width
                h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
            Next
```