# how to add custom header to datagridview print with visual basic

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I was able to print a data on a datagridview, and it prints without problem. now, i wanted to add a header text or image to the print out of the datagridview. i couldn't figure out how to do that. i have attached the code used to print the datagridview.

Private bitmap As Bitmap
    Private Sub btnprintreport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnprintreport.Click

```
    Try
        Dim height As Integer = reportsellinggridview.Height
        reportsellinggridview.Height = reportsellinggridview.RowCount * reportsellinggridview.RowTemplate.Height

        'Create a Bitmap and draw the DataGridView on it.
        bitmap = New Bitmap(Me.reportsellinggridview.Width, Me.reportsellinggridview.Height)
        reportsellinggridview.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.reportsellinggridview.Width, Me.reportsellinggridview.Height))

        'Resize DataGridView back to original height.
        reportsellinggridview.Height = height

        PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
        'Show the Print Preview Dialog.
        PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
        PrintPreviewDialog1.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = 1
        PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Could not print, please turn on the printer and make sure it is set as default printer", "print error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try



End Sub
Private Sub PrintPage(sender As Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    'Print the contents.
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: It's better to use RDLC Reports to print `DataGridView`. You cam simply pass `DataSource` of grid to the report. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511856/pass-datatable-to-reportviewer-vb)

Comment: would that also work if i added the rows of the datagridview with datagridview1.Rows.Add()

Comment: You need to pass a model to report. The model can be an `IList`, for example a `List<T>` or a `DataTable` that contains some columns, with the same name that you used in report. So if your `DataGridView` has not any `DataSource`, you can simply bind it to a `DataTable` and use it as report data source. You also can select all rows into a model, but using a `DataSource` is really better.