# Use a DataGridView as data source to Report Viewer

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to use a DataGridView as a data source to my report, I want to show the table in DataGridView in my report. I searched and the code that I found here in SO tell me to do something like that:

Button that generates the report

```
private void GenerateReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportForm reportForm = new ReportForm(DataGrid);
    reportForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

in my report form:

```
private DataGridView grid;

 private void ReportForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     DataTable dt = (DataTable)grid.DataSource;
     dt.TableName = "reportSource";

     reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
     ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("reportSource", dt);
     reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
     reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
     this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
  }
```

ReportForm's constructor

```
public ReportForm(DataGridView grid)
{
     InitializeComponent();
     this.grid = grid;
}
```

But I have an empty report.

Comment: Do you receive an exception or is any error shown in the report viewer?

Comment: Shouldn't you show us your ReportForm's constructor?  Change your constructor's parameters to just pass the DataTable, not the whole grid control.

Comment: No just an empty form, I will update the question with the ReportForm's constructor, but I already try to pass just the dataTable and I have the same result.

Comment: The problem couldn't be reproduced this way. I can *guess* some cases, for example you may have an empty report, you may have an empty data table, you may be using another report mistakenly. In other cases which currently come to my mind you should receive an exception. So make sure your report shows data at all. Also take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34512521/3110834) and follow steps to have a working example. It's a working step by step example.

Comment: Is the load event wired up?

Comment: yes the event is ok, ithis.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.ReportForm_Load); I will see the post and follow it. tks.

Comment: this line ReportForm reportForm = new ReportForm(DataGrid); DataGrid is the name of my DataGridView in my form.

Comment: What kind of report component do I have to have in my report.rdlc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix my problem adding a DataSet object in my application, then I use this code:

```
        private void ReportForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)grid.DataSource;
            ProgrammersDataSet ds = new ProgrammersDataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt.Copy());
            ds.Tables[1].TableName = "ProgrammersDataSet";
            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource(ds.Tables[1].TableName, ds.Tables[1]);

            reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Cerocha.Presentation.Reports.ProgrammersReport.rdlc";
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
```