# Using C# to dynamically set SSRS Report Datasource

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, reporting-services, rdlc, reportviewerformvc

I have made a SSRS rdl report which works well independently.

I need to run this report under my MVC project and set the Data-source to an IEnumerable

So far I've done this in my controller (with no luck):

```
var DataSetCity = dbContext.Cities.Where(p=>p.Id<5).ToList();

            ReportViewer r = new ReportViewer()
            {
                ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote,
                SizeToReportContent = true,
                Width = Unit.Percentage(100),
                Height = Unit.Percentage(100)


            };
            r.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/WaterReportServer/Report3";
            r.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://desktop-v4c0kc2/ReportServer/");


            ReportDataSource dataSource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet2", DataSetCity);

            r.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            r.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSource);
            ViewBag.RP = r;
            return View();
```

This code shows me a rendered report with original dataset that I used to design the report.

Is it possible to set my SSRS report dynamically ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set Datatable as datasource in ReportViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458434/how-to-set-datatable-as-datasource-in-reportviewer)

Comment: There are number of posts here with answers to exact same question, for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458434/how-to-set-datatable-as-datasource-in-reportviewer
Also, check out the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252094.aspx