# how to bind Report Viewer manually

Tags: c#, sql-server, data-binding, reportviewer

i want to bind the report viewer using codes not the wizard in such way, the user type the table name inside a textBox, and then, the table are viewed in the report viewer.

BUT first of all i want the code to bind the database to the report viewer

THANKS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34458615/4156974 this answer might help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set Datatable as datasource in ReportViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458434/how-to-set-datatable-as-datasource-in-reportviewer)